# How to secure a Database of 450 MB in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, security, android-sqlite

I am creating an app having a large **database file of 450 MB**. I am storing it in SD card. I want to secure it as it has some sensitive data. If anyone can tell me the best way to do it, it will solve my problem.

I also tried a sample but it was working for small DB file. If I am using 450 MB Db, it is not working and it takes a very long time.

**And also please let me know whether it is possible or not to secure such a  large data.**

Comment: Possibly, keep the database on the server and access it through WebServices.

Comment: Actually my app is fully offline.

Comment: Actually. Maybe, in the future, you'll need real security.

Answer (score 4):

It kind of is, but not really.  You can encrypt it, and get the decryption key from a server.  There is no other way to secure it, as the user can always pop the sd card into an sd card reader.  And if the decryption key is local they can decompile your app.

Here's the problem-  the encrypted file can't be used by SQLite.  So you'd have to decrypt it to disk, and it can be grabbed at that point.  So no, its not really possible to secure a database file at all.  You're better off keeping the information on a server and querying it via webservice if you want to keep the data secret.

Comment: Thanks for giving me valuable suggetion but, I am not using any web service, this app is fully offline.

Comment: Then you can't secure your data.  If a device outside of your control has the data and the means to decrypt it there's always a way to get at it.  You can make it slightly harder, but its still a matter of minimal effort and understanding of reverse engineering.

Comment: I think an USB cable is enough to pop the db aout of the SD card, if the db is not inside the `assets` or the `/data/data/...` folder. ;)

Comment: Isn't that much harder if it is. The apk is just a signed zip. Do an adv pull and grab it.  Also not sure how he plans on distributing as 450 mb is easy over the play store max apk size

Comment: He might use an expansion file... which is a zip file too. But, that is, I just wanted to say that... I have an **unused SDCard reader**, too! ;)